# Using Consolas for listing in Overleaf

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

It's known that the default TT font family is too wide. I would try to use Consolas to list my code instead, since a lot of people are familiar with this programmer-oriented font. At the same time, I'm using Oevrleaf and Overleaf does not have Consolas with it. Overleaf tells me I can [add a font](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F). Then I got question 1:

The font that I downloaded is multiple .ttf files. I put the files in the same folder and tried something like

```
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{Consolas}{m}{Consolas} #1 }}
```

But the font is not correct.

Question 2: The command above would allow be to use Consolas if it got fixed. But how can I set it to be the default font for `lstlisting`?

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions are best posted to the Overleaf helpdesk. Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.

Comment: Try with `\newcommand{customfon}[1]{\bgroup\fontspec[ Path = ./]{Consolas}\selectfont#1\egroup}`

Comment: pdftex can not read ttf fonts to get the metrics, you could convert a subset of the font to tfm or (much easier) make sure you are using luatex or xetex then you can access the font using `fontspec` package (do not use `T1` encoding in that case)